# How do I add a template into the header panel? Magento-2.1.7 Porto Template

Tags: template, header, layout-update, magento-2.1.7

I created the modified default.xml and created headerContent.phtml to add new content to the header panel to be position on the opposite side of the login and welcome msg.  However, after uploading, modifying and clearing all caches, my new content isn't showing up on the page at all.

> Vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.content" template="Magento_Theme::headerContent.phtml" before="header.links" />
        </referenceContainer>    
    </body>
</page>
```

> Vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/templates/headerContent.phtml

```
Hello World!
```

What am i doing wrong? did i use the wrong location or a typo somewhere?

Comment: modified to change /templates/html/ to /templates/ - mistyped the folder directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed out `html` in the template path.

So change

```
template="Magento_Theme::headerContent.phtml"
```

To

```
template="Magento_Theme::html/headerContent.phtml"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i will adjust its just in templates not templates/html. my mistake.  any other errors other than that? it didnt work for me.

Comment: Not that I can see, have you cleared caches?

Comment: I don't think it matters but Magento don't use camel case for template names, you could try changing `headerContent` to `header_content` and see if that makes a difference. Again clear Magento cache after making that change

Comment: thanks. I changed it to header_content.  definitely flushed and cleared caches.  still a no go.  not sure why.  not responding at all.

Comment: do i have to redeploy the theme for it to take effect? thats the only thing i didnt do.

Comment: If you mean the static content deploy then I don't think that will help, it's worth a try though :( Whenever I run into situations like that it's usually either a typo or caching. To rule out varnish cache try running `sudo service varnish restart`.